# Refering the image in "href" rather than url in anchor tag in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

Check out my code here as,

```
<a href="image_link1">
<img src="image_link1"></img>
</a>
```

Here img link is same as that of href( when img is clicked, it should open a popup of same img), the challenge is i don't want to use "image_link1" in href, instead i need to use something which refer to same image as that in the img. Anyone has any idea or suggestion, even if you have idea to do it in javascript are welcome.
In simple we are assigning URL to the href="url". But i don't want to assign URL to my href. I want to give anything other than URL, like variable in javascript which refers the image inside my anchor tag.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please explain bit more.

Comment: we are assigning URL to the href="url". But i don't want to assign URL to my href. I want to give anything other than URL, like variable in javascript which refers the image inside my anchor tag. Am i clear?

Comment: search for how to use `attr` in `jquery` You'll find the solution. You can check below answers also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to open pop up of same image please,check out this
 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/varunaaruru/eDMmy/127/)

```
<img class='img' src="http://www.petelepage.com/assets/gela1.png" onclick="ChangeUrl()" id="image1">        
    <div id="myDialog">
       <img class='img' src="http://www.petelepage.com/assets/gela1.png">
    </div>
       <script>
           function ChangeUrl(){ 
         $("#myDialog").dialog("open")
           }
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen  : false,
    modal     : true,
});
</script>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function`
I got this error.. by running your code.. why it occurs?

Comment: Include jquery in your index.HTML file

Comment: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`
It is already added in my index file

Comment: i am using latest jquery ui and is working fine..
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: i tried with the latest version also. it is still not working

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').attr('src',$('img').attr('href'))
});
```

Comment: It's other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/gjEou8OwWDrR5EmFOafm?p=preview

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('href',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know I understand the problem, but maybe this helps:

```
<a href="#" class="pic"> <!--using a class-->
    <img src="image_link1"></img>
</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.pic').each(function(){ // Foreach a.pic
            var url = $(this).find('img').attr('src'); // Get src 
            $(this).attr("href",url); // Set href
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you don't want the a-tag:

```
$('img').bind('click',function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both links are same then you do not need to write both tags.

just write code:-

```
<a href="image_link1"> </a>

<script>
   var Img = $('a').attr('href');
   $('a').prepend("<img src="+Img+">");
</script>
```